# Can't compile gradle vaadin project in Intellij

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, gradle, vaadin

I want to try out Vaadin 7 with java 8, gradle 2.1, and IntelliJ 13.1.5 on Mac OSX. I installed gradle with brew. Here's what I've done so far

- I created a project using the gradle wizard in Intellij
- I set up tomcat like this [Creating a Project with Intellij IDEA](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/getting-started.idea.html) vaadin tutorial.
- I've added the [vaadin-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin) to my `build.gradle` file.
- I hit the gradle refresh button
- I ran `vaadinCreateProject` in the intellij gradle plugin menu
- I made sure my `JAVA_HOME` and `GRADLE_HOME` point to correct locations

Everything works correctly with gradle commands, I ran `vaadinRun` and navigated `http://localhost://8080` and saw the hello world.  But IntelliJ has all identifiers highlighted red with "cannot resolve symbol". I've tried every form of recompiling and clearing caches.

How can I get Intellij recognize the code?

My gradle.build file.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: 'http://plugins.jasoft.fi/vaadin.plugin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

[image: First IntelliJ Screenshot]
[image: Second IntelliJ Screenshot]

Comment: with "all identifiers" you mean only vaadin stuff or more?

Comment: I've added images of the errors. It's both vaadin and javax classes.

Comment: and the stuff under `External Libraries` in the project tree mainly consists only of the JDK and junit?  i would suspect, that IDEA is not able to cope with the gradle configs the vaadin plugin is using to get the deps... or of course it could be some random IDEA fsckup we all love so much ;)

Comment: Yes, `External Libraries` only shows hamcrest-core and junit.

Comment: when you run `gradle dependencies`, you will see, that there are lots of configs.  IDEA most likely picks up only `default` or `compile` and it is again most likely very empty.  You could add some of the common vaadin deps like `-server`, `-client`, `-themes` to your deps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/getting-started-with-vaadin.html),
Vaadin plugin requires Gradle 3.0+

```
// Vaadin plugin requires Gradle 3.0+
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.0'
}
```

I am not sure your project will be OK with that spoon of groovy, but without it it shouldn't work.

Comment: I don't even remember asking this question, but sure I'll believe you :)

Answer (score 2):

The Vaadin Gradle plugin injects the Vaadin dependencies at runtime which Intellij's JetGradle plugin does not pick up for some reason.

What you can do instead is use the Gradle idea plugin (apply plugin: 'idea' in your build.gradle) and run the idea task. After that import the project into Intellij and all dependencies should be on the classpath.

Whenever you add a dependency you need to run the idea task again so the classpath is updated.